# Importing Cython header file into C code and compiling it with Xcode

Tags: python, c, xcode, cython

I am trying to import a cython .h file into C and then calling the function inside of my .h file. But when I try to build the main.c file I get lots of errors.

I started with this file:
helloworld.pyx

```
cdef function1()
    print("test1234")
```

Then I ran `cython helloworld.pyx` and got the `helloworld.h`file. So till then everything worked fine. After that I wrote a small C program to call that function inside of the cython script which looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Python.h>
#include "helloworld.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

For now I didn`t even call the function inside of helloworld.h but I am getting lots of errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_PyBytes_FromStringAndSize", referenced from:
      ___pyx_pymod_exec_helloworld in helloworld.o
      ___Pyx_InitStrings in helloworld.o
  "_PyCode_New", referenced from:
      ___Pyx_CreateCodeObjectForTraceback in helloworld.o
  "_PyDict_GetItemString", referenced from:
      ___pyx_pymod_exec_helloworld in helloworld.o
  "_PyDict_New", referenced from:
      ___pyx_pymod_exec_helloworld in helloworld.o
      ___Pyx_Print in helloworld.o
  "_PyDict_SetItem", referenced from:
      ___pyx_pymod_exec_helloworld in helloworld.o
      ___Pyx_Print in helloworld.o
  "_PyDict_SetItemString", referenced from:
      ___pyx_pymod_exec_helloworld in helloworld.o
      ___Pyx_copy_spec_to_module in helloworld.o
  "_PyErr_Clear", referenced from:
      ___Pyx_copy_spec_to_module in helloworld.o
      ___Pyx_CLineForTraceback in helloworld.o
  "_PyErr_ExceptionMatches", referenced from:
      ___Pyx_copy_spec_to_module in helloworld.o
  "_PyErr_Occurred", referenced from:
      ___pyx_pymod_exec_helloworld in helloworld.o
  "_PyErr_SetString", referenced from:
      ___pyx_pymod_exec_helloworld in helloworld.o
      ___Pyx_check_single_interpreter in helloworld.o
  "_PyErr_WarnEx", referenced from:
      ___Pyx_check_binary_version in helloworld.o
  "_PyExc_AttributeError", referenced from:
      ___Pyx_copy_spec_to_module in helloworld.o
  "_PyExc_ImportError", referenced from:
      ___pyx_pymod_exec_helloworld in helloworld.o
      ___Pyx_check_single_interpreter in helloworld.o
  "_PyExc_RuntimeError", referenced from:
      ___pyx_pymod_exec_helloworld in helloworld.o
  "_PyFrame_New", referenced from:
      ___Pyx_AddTraceback in helloworld.o
  "_PyImport_AddModule", referenced from:
      ___pyx_pymod_exec_helloworld in helloworld.o
  "_PyImport_GetModuleDict", referenced from:
      ___pyx_pymod_exec_helloworld in helloworld.o
  "_PyInterpreterState_GetID", referenced from:
      ___Pyx_check_single_interpreter in helloworld.o
  "_PyMem_Malloc", referenced from:
      ___pyx_insert_code_object in helloworld.o
  "_PyMem_Realloc", referenced from:
      ___pyx_insert_code_object in helloworld.o
  "_PyModuleDef_Init", referenced from:
      _PyInit_helloworld in helloworld.o
  "_PyModule_GetDict", referenced from:
      ___pyx_pymod_create in helloworld.o
      ___pyx_pymod_exec_helloworld in helloworld.o
  "_PyModule_NewObject", referenced from:
      ___pyx_pymod_create in helloworld.o
  "_PyOS_snprintf", referenced from:
      ___Pyx_check_binary_version in helloworld.o
  "_PyObject_Call", referenced from:
      ___Pyx_Print in helloworld.o
  "_PyObject_GetAttr", referenced from:
      ___Pyx_Print in helloworld.o
      ___Pyx_PyObject_GetAttrStr in helloworld.o
  "_PyObject_GetAttrString", referenced from:
      ___pyx_pymod_create in helloworld.o
      ___Pyx_copy_spec_to_module in helloworld.o
  "_PyObject_Hash", referenced from:
      ___Pyx_InitStrings in helloworld.o
  "_PyObject_Not", referenced from:
      ___Pyx_CLineForTraceback in helloworld.o
  "_PyObject_SetAttr", referenced from:
      ___pyx_pymod_exec_helloworld in helloworld.o
      ___Pyx_CLineForTraceback in helloworld.o
  "_PyObject_SetAttrString", referenced from:
      ___pyx_pymod_exec_helloworld in helloworld.o
  "_PyThreadState_Get", referenced from:
      ___Pyx_check_single_interpreter in helloworld.o
  "_PyTraceBack_Here", referenced from:
      ___Pyx_AddTraceback in helloworld.o
  "_PyTuple_New", referenced from:
      ___pyx_pymod_exec_helloworld in helloworld.o
  "_PyTuple_Pack", referenced from:
      ___Pyx_PrintOne in helloworld.o
  "_PyUnicode_Decode", referenced from:
      ___Pyx_InitStrings in helloworld.o
  "_PyUnicode_FromFormat", referenced from:
      ___Pyx_CreateCodeObjectForTraceback in helloworld.o
  "_PyUnicode_FromString", referenced from:
      ___Pyx_CreateCodeObjectForTraceback in helloworld.o
  "_PyUnicode_FromStringAndSize", referenced from:
      ___pyx_pymod_exec_helloworld in helloworld.o
      ___Pyx_InitStrings in helloworld.o
      ___Pyx_Print in helloworld.o
  "_PyUnicode_InternFromString", referenced from:
      ___Pyx_InitStrings in helloworld.o
  "_Py_GetVersion", referenced from:
      ___Pyx_check_binary_version in helloworld.o
  "__PyDict_GetItem_KnownHash", referenced from:
      ___Pyx_CLineForTraceback in helloworld.o
  "__PyObject_GetDictPtr", referenced from:
      ___Pyx_CLineForTraceback in helloworld.o
  "__PyThreadState_UncheckedGet", referenced from:
      ___Pyx_AddTraceback in helloworld.o
  "__Py_Dealloc", referenced from:
      __Py_DECREF in helloworld.o
  "__Py_FalseStruct", referenced from:
      ___Pyx_CLineForTraceback in helloworld.o
  "__Py_NoneStruct", referenced from:
      ___Pyx_copy_spec_to_module in helloworld.o
  "__Py_TrueStruct", referenced from:
      ___Pyx_CLineForTraceback in helloworld.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Is there any way to fix my problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: They're just linking errors because you haven't linked against libpython.

Comment: Okay and how can I link libpython? I am very new to Xcode so sorry for this question.

Comment: I don't know - I don't use Xcode. But if you search something like "how to link external library in xcode" I suspect you'll find something useful

Comment: On the linux command-line it'd just be the extra arguments `-L<path-to-python -lpython<maybe a version?>`. You can find out the paths with `python-config --libs` I think

Comment: For some reason if I do `-lpython38` it gives me the error, `Library not found for -lpython38`. But thank you very much for your help.

Comment: That's what the `-L<path>` tells it - the place to find the library.

Comment: So now I think it's working. But I am still getting errors. The same as before but less.